# Panda how to overwrite new value on previous value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code :

```
# Append columns to an empty DataFrame.
    self.df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["ID", "Features"],index=['index1'])
```

```
tracking_id = output[4]
print(tracking_id in set(self.df['ID']))
if tracking_id in self.df['ID'] : 
                 
      df2 = pd.DataFrame([[tracking_id], features])
      self.df.update(df2)  
      print(self.df)
    
else : 
     self.df = self.df.append({'ID' : tracking_id, 'Features' : features}, ignore_index = True)
```

In this code, first I check whether an element with the same İD is available or not. Is it is available, previous feature value should be updated with the new one. Actually it works but not correctly.

My output is :

```
    ID                                           Features
0  NaN                                                NaN
1  1.0  [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0...
2  4.0  [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 89.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10...
3  4.0  [[70.0, 41.0, 17.0, 41.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
4  4.0  [[42.0, 18.0, 16.0, 14.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
5  6.0  [[3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 8.0, 59.0...
6  6.0  [[0.0, 6.0, 7.0, 9.0, 12.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 51....
```

As you can see, the same value is appended like absent İD on the list. However sometimes it is not added to the list just is overwrited to previous ones. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Hard to understand unless we see before and after snapshot. Please recreate the problem with smaller dataset. It is difficult to focus with so many numbers.

Comment: I can not change the dataset unfortunately, cause I get it from webcam. Those are descriptors of the detected images. But I can say that the only thing what you should consider is elements of ID column.